# Add button after a div with script on wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, button

I need to append a button after one div in my wordpress, i try this snippet but its not working, any idea how should it be? Thanks.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var posicion = document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-search");
    var boton = document.createElement("button");
    boton.innerHTML = "Ver/Ocultar filtros";
    posicion.appendChild(boton);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which has no appendChild method. if you need to append the button on every element with the class "sf-field-search" you need to iterate the elements in "posicion" and append the button, otherwise you can do `document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-search")[0]` and  it will append the button on the first element found with the class "sf-field-search"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery it can be done like this. I included a class on the button to style it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var posicion = $('.sf-field-search');
  posicion.append('<button class="test">Ver/Ocultar filtros</button>');
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.test:hover {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sf-field-search">sf-field-search</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate!!